# Can't pass a List<Guid> as a parameter to a web-service in SL3

Tags: c#, web-services, silverlight-3.0, parameter-passing

I have the following web-method:

```
namespace MessageService{
...
    [WebMethod]
    public ServiceReturnCodes SetMsg(List<Guid> Ids, DateTime processDateTime)
    {
        BL.SetMsg(Ids, DateTime.Now);   
    }
}
```

But when I call this method:

```
public List<Guid> Ids = new List<Guid>();
...
service.SetMsg(Ids, DateTime.Now);
```

I get the following error: Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'MessageWeb.MessageService.ArrayOfGuid'
I can't figure out what `ArrayOfGuid` is and why it tries to convert.

Comment: ArrayOfGuid is the name of the complex type that is defined in your WSDL.

Comment: Yup, just found it. I don't remember doing it though, can/should I get rid of it and just use a simple List<>?

Comment: Why not just use WCF and not have this sort of problem?

Comment: @John: my project is a part of a bigger one in .net 3.5, so i can't really change anything

Comment: @Masha: are you using a web reference in your SL3 project? Try a service reference instead, and you may be able to specify to use `List<T>` for collections.

Comment: @John: no, i'm using a Service Reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just able to use `ArrayOfGuid` type to create a list and pass it as a parameter:

```
ArrayOfGuid Ids = null;
Ids.Add(Id);
....
service.SetMsg(Ids, DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to convert it to an array using

service.SetMsg(Ids.ToArray() , DateTime.Now);

Answer (score 1):

hi: yo can AddRange method to add elements to and of list :

```
[WebMethod]
public ServiceReturnCodes SetMsg(List<Guid> Ids, DateTime processDateTime)
{
    ArrayOfGuid _Ids = new List<Guid>();
    _Ids.AddRange(Ids);
    BL.SetMsg(_Ids, DateTime.Now);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you'll find that the `ArrayOfGuid` *is* `List<Guid>`. Look in the Reference.cs. Here's what's in mine:

```
public class ArrayOfGuid : System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Guid> {}
```

So far, I've been able to use the partial class feature to make it a little easier to just pass a `List<Guid>`:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1.MessageServiceProxy
{
    partial class ArrayOfGuid
    {
        public ArrayOfGuid()
        {
        }

        public ArrayOfGuid(IEnumerable<Guid> guids) : base(guids)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to pass `new ArrayOfGuid(yourListOfGuid)`.

Comment: Actually, I was just able to use this created for me `ArrayOfGuid`-type and pass it.